# Convergence of complex series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{e^{in(\alpha + \frac{\pi}{2})}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to judge on convergence of sequence:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{e^{in(\alpha + \frac{\pi}{2})}}{n}$$

where $\alpha \in [0, 2 \pi]$. I read in my book that when $e^{in(\alpha + \frac{\pi}{2})} \neq 1$ then sequence converges due to Dirichlet test.

Of course when $e^{in(\alpha + \frac{\pi}{2})} = 1$  its obvious that series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac 1 n$ does not converge.

In case of $e^{in(\alpha + \frac{\pi}{2})} \neq 1$ for Dirichlet test we have to show several prerequisites. First of first $\frac 1 n$ is monotonically decreasing down to $0$ (obvious), and less obvious that sequence $\sum_{n = 1}^N e^{in(\alpha + \frac{\pi}{2})}$ is bounded.

In the book they treat it as something obvious but I have hard time with proving so.

$$\sum_{n =1}^Ne^{in(\alpha + \frac \pi 2)} = e^{in \frac \pi 2} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{in\alpha}  =$$
$$=e^{in \frac \pi 2}[e^{i\alpha} + e^{2i\alpha}+...e^{Ni\alpha}] = 
e^{in \frac \pi 2e^{i \alpha}}\frac{1 - e^{ni\alpha}}{1 - e^{i\alpha}}
$$

How can I say that for any $N$ above sum is bounded?

Comment: Do you know how to compute a geometric sum?

Comment: I updated my question... still not sure how to prove boundness

Comment: Do the same calculation without pulling out $e^{in\pi /2}$ and use the fact that $e^{i\theta}$ is bounded.

Comment: How do you know that $e^{i \theta}$ is bounded?

Comment: $|e^{i\theta}|=1$ if $\theta$ is real.